# Ignore column with specific value by default in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How do I make a column work similar to how `deleted_at` works for `SoftDelete`. I.e if it `null` the model is returned if it has a value skip it?

I have `Student` model with `graduated` column that has a default value `-1`:

I need to make it so that models with:

```php
value == 1
```

Ignore it by default as with `deleted_at`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using [Laravel's Global Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#global-scopes).

On your `Student` model you register the scope in its boot method:

```php
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('onlyGraduated', function ($builder) {
        $builder->where('graduated', 1);
    });
}
```

Like `SoftDeletes` has `withTrashed` you can add a local scope to include these if you want.

```php
public function scopeWithUngraduated($query)
{
    $query->withoutGlobalScope('onlyGraduated');
}
```

So that when you call:

```php
Student::query()->get() // only graduated students are returned
```

but

```php
Student::query()->withUngraduated()->get() // all are returned
```

I'm not sure if you wanted to return graduated by default or ungraduated by default. In that case you just "flip the switch" of course.

Tip: **always** remember to call `parent::boot()` when overriding the boot method.

Comment: @mohamedammar that's great. Glad to help.